# EF CodeFirst: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges except one table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

So I use this role:

```
DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges
```

But theres one table that I to preserve its data..
So is there a way to exclude one table or to preserve one table data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to exclude a table, because as the name implies it will Drop the whole database.

However you can inherit from the intializer and override the seed method to reinsert your data:

```
public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        //insert data to tables through context
    }
}
```

If you want something more complex you need to implement `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>` directly, something like:

```
public class MyComplexInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
{ 
    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Exists())
        {
             if (context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                 return;
             //do something bofore delete
             context.Database.Delete();
        }
        context.Database.Create();
        //add some data to context
        context.SaveChanges();                 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have something like that and in the end of the seed I have context.SaveChanges(); But where do I specified to drop table/db?

Comment: If you have inherited from `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` when the model changes then first it will automatically drop the DB; recreate all the tables; and then it calls the `Seed` method. There is no additional config needed except that you set your initialzer with `Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer());` at app start.

Comment: Is there pre drop database method?

Comment: No, there is no pre drop hook. If you want something that complex implement `IDatabaseInitializer<TContext>` see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not by dropping the entire database (that's what those roles do). I can imagine you can create your own role that explicitly execute DROP queries for all tables except the one you'd like to keep.